# Case-insensitive IN for python

Tags: python

Is there a way to do a SQL-like `IN` statement in python. For example:

```
'hello' in ['Hello', 'Goodbye'] # case insensitive
True
```

I was thinking a list comprehension to rebuild the list, but hopefully there is something much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the list to `str.lower`:

```
if 'hello' in map(str.lower, ['Hello', 'Goodbye']):
```

In Python 3.x, this will not build a new list since `map` returns an iterator.  In Python 2.x, you can achieve the same by importing [`itertools.imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap).

---

Alternately, you could just use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
if 'hello' in (x.lower() for x in ['Hello', 'Goodbye']):
```

This is lazy too and works the same in both versions.

Answer (score 3):

A generator expression using `any` would be one of the more efficient ways, it will lazily evaluate short circuiting if we find a match:

```
l =['Hello', 'Goodbye'] 
s = "hello"
if any(s == x.lower() for x in l):
    ....

In [10]: l =['Hello', 'Goodbye']   
In [11]: s = "hello"    
In [12]: any(s == x.lower() for x in l)
Out[12]: True
```